# How to run express app on port 80 without sudo access

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, express

I am using the express framework for nodejs on a Dreamhost VPS and I want to run my server on port 80 but all of the answers I've seen require sudo/root access but on a Dreamhost VPS I am not given this permission. I can't edit any of the Apache files. The only thing I am able to do is create a `.htaccess` file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this and has Dreamhost, the solution I came up with was creating a proxy. In the Dreamhost panel there is an option to create a proxy for a domain that you can then direct to go to any port for that domain and I simply made the proxy go to port `3000` and then my node server ran on port `3000`.

@Frxstrem's answer also works but it failed to work when I shared a link and is kind of a hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run Node on a different port (greater than 1024, since those of 1023 or lower require root) and just proxy the requests through Apache by adding something like this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

(In this example Node would be running on port 8080).

Comment: Where would I put my `.htaccess` file? Currently on my vps I have several domains and in the domain `example.com` is where node server is.

Comment: Do you have one directory per domain? If so, I'd try putting it in that directory.

Comment: I put it in the directory that contains the node app and it didn't seem to work

Comment: I got it to work by adding this line `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
` in the middle of the two statements. Is this method safe to use?